# Creating an infix function

Tags: haskell

I am currently trying to create an infix function of |= ( Every A is B, Syllogism ).

```
(|=) :: Predicate Thing -> Predicate Thing -> Bool
a |= b = [ if a == b then True | x <- a , y <- b ]
```

The problem is I am getting an parse error on input `|`

Any Help would be Appreciated !

Comment: Your `if ... then` needs an `else`, first of all.

Comment: can you explain in words what you want this function to do? (The definitions of the types`Predicate` and `Thing` are probably necessary too.) I can't make much sense of your attempt - for one thing, you appear to be trying to return a list of some kind, which does not match the stated return type of `Bool`.

Comment: Whenever you get an error/rejection (parsing or type solving or whatever), tell what the error is, and where exactly in the code the message is pointing to. Usually for newbie code, the error message is a very helpful clue. (Where Haskellers complain about GHC's error reporting is in dense, complex bits of code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the list comprehension. You can not write an `if … then …`. An `if … then … else …` is an expression, not a statement.

If you want to return `True` if one of the elements of `a` is equal to one of the elements of `b`, you can work with [**`or :: Foldable f => f Bool -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:or):

```
(|=) :: Predicate Thing -> Predicate Thing -> Bool
a |= b = or [ a == b | x <- a , y <- b ]
```

or you can work with `any` and `elem`:

```
(|=) :: (Foldable f, Foldable g, Eq a) => f a -> g a -> Bool
a |= b = any (`elem` b) a
```

This however only works if `Predicate` is list, or at least a `Foldable` in the second case. Not for a custom type (that is not an instance of `Foldable`).